# Присвоение текста одного поля другому PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Текст не хочет присваиваться из `lineEdit` в `textEdit_2` после нажатия `pushButton`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       MainWindow.resize(2417, 957)
       self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
       self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
       self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
       self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
       self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
       self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
       self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
       self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
       self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
       self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
       self.label.setObjectName("label")
       self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
       self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
       self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
       self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
       self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
       self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
       self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
       self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
       self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
       self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
       self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
       self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
       self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
       self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
       self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
       self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
       self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
       self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
       self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
       self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
       self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
       self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
       self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
       self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
       self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
       self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
       self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
       self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
       self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
       self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
       self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
       self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
       self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
       self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
       self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
       self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
       self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
       self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
       self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
       self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
       self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
       self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
       self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
       MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
       self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2417, 20))
       self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
       MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
       self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
       self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
       MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

       self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
       self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
       self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
       self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
       self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
       self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
       self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
       self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
       self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
       self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
       self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
       self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
       self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))

   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
       

   def on_button_click(self):
           message = self.textEdit_2.setText(self.lineEdit.text())

   ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(on_button_click)

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(2417, 957)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2417, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

    def on_button_click(self):
        self.textEdit_2.setText(self.lineEdit.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почти одновременно ответили :)

Comment: @gil9red бывает :)

Answer (score 3):

У вас там будет ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'textEdit_2'

Причина в том, что сигнал **clicked** у кнопки передает флаг `checked` у самой кнопки, поэтому в функцию `on_button_click` и передается значение `bool`

А вам нужно работать с самими виджетами.

---

**Первый вариант.** Работать напрямую через `ui`:

```
...
    def on_button_click():
        ui.textEdit_2.setText(ui.lineEdit.text())

    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(on_button_click)
...
```

---

**Второй вариант.** Сделайте свой виджет и в нем используйте ту функцию. Думаю, это самый правильный.

Весь код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(2417, 957)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2417, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

    def on_button_click(self):
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(self.ui.lineEdit.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```